# Can't run any apt-get update without killing server

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I have an ubuntu 12.04.2 that dies after I tried to do an upgrade on it.

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

So I run that and get the following output.

```
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-29-virtual
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Setting up openjdk-6-jre-headless (6b27-1.12.3-0ubuntu1~12.04) ...
Connection to ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com closed.
```

Anyone seen this behavior before?

Comment: find out if OOM killer is to blame (with dmesg and/or /var/log/syslog)

Comment: So what is the output after that? Do you see command prompt? Do you have network connection after that?